# Difficult to alter and separate REQUEST_URI with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, request-uri

I'm trying to treat a URL with htaccess and %{REQUEST_URI} parameter.  I researched a lot, use htaccess.madewithlove.be and a virtual machine to build the rule and test without success.

The Request URL is:

> 1) www.example.com.br/category/product/Beer?id=16

Anothe example of requested URL to better understanding:

> 2) www.example.com.br/category/product/Wine?id=33

The rule I created is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com\.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)category/product/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/$1? [R=301,L]
```

The expected rewrite are:

> 1) www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/Beer
>
> 2) www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/Wine

But, using this rule the output URL are:

> 1) www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/category/product/Beer
>
> 2) www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/category/product/Wine

In this case I put hardly category/product in the output to simplify since I couldn't separate using $0, $1 and $2 directives.  Anyone has a idea how to solve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a condition on `REQUEST_URI` since you can match it in `RewriteRule`.

Instead, you can use this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/product/([^/]+)$ http://www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Or you could use `REQUEST_URI` like you did (both are correct)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/product/([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mynewsite.com.br/category/product/luxe-product/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worked!  I have a doubt, my mistake was using (.*) in the RewriteRule, right?.  I don't understand yet this part of the rules.  I need to study more.  Can you suggest a good tutorial?  Thanks and best regards.